# java script onclick() function not called

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp, onclick

I have a search page which takes time to load results on submit. So i decided to show a loading.gif to keep the user entertained while it loads. below is the javascript function, the div element on jsp and the call to the javascript function.

JS

```
function goodbye(){
console.log();
var pb = document.getElementById("loading");
pb.innerHTML = '<img src= "images/loadingAnimation.gif" />';
pb.style.display = 'block';
return true;
}
```

div

```
<div id="loading" style="position:absolute; width:100%; text-align:20%; top:100px; height: auto; left: 500px;"></div>
```

Call to JS

```
<td><html:submit property="method" value="Submit"
                    onclick="return goodbye();" styleClass="btn2" /></td>
```

i even get "LOG:" on the console. and all java script is on the same page between script tags and not in a seperate .js file

Edit: I have the div tag between the body tag and form tag.

Comment: Check that the relative path to your image is actually correct from the location of your JSP.

Comment: I think either the css is faulty or your image does not exist. What happens if you check it in Firebug? Do you see errors in the console?

Comment: I dont see any errors. The image is actually present in my images folder and the path to it is correct. If i debug it in IE developer tools, and go step by step, the image shows up. and all consecutive runs show the image. But if i clear cache and run it normally without debugging in IE dev tools, the image never shows.

Comment: Your code is fine. verify the path of   of image `<img src= "images/loadingAnimation.jpg" />` and also remove `console.log();` if you are testing in IE

Answer (score 0):

i have tried your code, and it is working  for me.. 
[image]

```
function goodbye() {
        console.log();
        var pb = document.getElementById("loading");
        pb.innerHTML = '<img src= "../images/loading.gif" />';
        pb.style.display = 'block';
        return true;
    }
```

what i have noticed is, div placement is  the position:absolute is causing the problem, because you div will be placed to relative to your parent div. it might be placed some where else than what you were expecting.

i have given the border to debug. you can try this.

```
 <div id="loading" style="width: 100%;  border:2px solid black"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me when i mover the img tag into the div.

```
<div id="loading" style="display:none; position:absolute; width:100%; text-align:20%; top:100px; height: auto; left: 400px;">
<img src= "images/load.gif" /></div>
```

But thanks to everyone who tried.

Answer (score -1):

replace `onclick="return goodbye();"` with `onclick="goodbye()"`

Comment: I did try that and nothing changed.